# My wifi doesn't connect

Tags: wireless, networking

I have been using ubuntu 14.10 on my old computer for about 6 months with no problem.
I just installed ubuntu 14.10 on my new laptop (some Dell laptop)  and it does not detect any wifi, although there is a connection available.  (When I go back an forth to windows and back to Ubuntu, windows always detects the wifi connection and Ubuntu does not).
Can you please help me with this issue? 
Thanks a lot!!!!

＊info from comment

`rfkill list all` gives me:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` gives me:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network connection [8086:1502] (rev 04) 
    Subsystem: Dell device [1028:0493]
    Kernel driver in uses e1000e 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359] 
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1530 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:0011]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Can you add the results of the followings commands in terminal? `rfkill list all` and `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`

Comment: "rfkill list all" gives me: 0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN                           Soft blocked: no                                                                  Hard blocked: no

Comment: "lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net" gives me:  00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)  Subsystem: Dell device [1028:0493]  Kernel driver in uses e1000e  --  02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]  Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1530 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:0011]  Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: I added ** every place the line skiped:                                           "lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net" gives me: 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network connection [8086:1502] (rev 04) ** Subsystem: Dell device [1028:0493] ** Kernel driver in uses e1000e ** -- ** 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359] ** Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1530 Half-size Mini PCIe Card [1028:0011] ** Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r ssb` and see if wifi works, if not do `sudo modprobe -r bcma`

Comment: my battery is dead and I don't have a charger, I'll try it in the morning.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: neither worked.....  :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the proprietary driver for your Broadcom wireless card.

Please press the super key (the windows key) to open your dash, and search "driver" for it: [image: Search driver in dash]

And open the "Additional Drivers", select the driver and click "Apply changes":

[image: Additional driver]

Comment: "additional drivers" is empty by me.  Can I download the driver on another computer and then install it on my ubuntu?   If yes, where do I find it?   Can I download it on windows and then transfer it with a disk-on-key to ubuntu?

Comment: @MW Sure: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx BTW, can your laptop reach the Internet with Ethernet port? You will need to update the software list first (run `sudo apt-get update` in your terminal)

Comment: That driver should be on the DVD/USB that you installed Ubuntu with in /pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/